# Qt addressBook example part 2 unable to set GeoMetry

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I try to start with a GUI with QT. Currently I understand the addressbook part 2 of the QT examples, but I have a small question about it.

When I start the example just out of the box I get this message:

> Starting D:\Qt\5.1.1\msvc2010\examples\widgets\tutorials\addressbook\build-part2-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\part2.exe...
>   setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 75x23+480+190 on 'QPushButtonClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  116x23+480+190 (frame: 8, 30, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
>   void QWindowsClipboard::propagateClipboardMessage(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) const: Cowardly refusing to send clipboard message to application under debugger...
>   void QWindowsClipboard::propagateClipboardMessage(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) const: Cowardly refusing to send clipboard message to application under debugger...

I'm  using Qt Creator 5.1.1

I'm not really sure how to fix this message and I can't really find anything about this topic on the web.

I want to fix this message while I don't know what the problem is. Actually there is not really an error, the application works perfectly but i dont like warnings like these without knowing where they actually come from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you try to build this example without a debugger attached to your process, as it seems `QWindowsClipBoard` don't like it

Comment: I just tried but it makes no difference. The message is exactly the same.

Comment: I had this problem when running a project I took over on a 13" screen instead of 24". Changing to 24" got it right again.

Comment: I still have the problem actually. Still can't find what the reason is